# Error: A newer version is available. To modify this document, open the latest

Tags: document-library, version

I am using sp 2010. I have a document library. When I try to upload a new document and set the metadata everything is OK. When I open this word document from the library I see some message in Microsoft Office Word:

> A newer version is available. To modify this document, open the latest
>   version or save a copy.

Why do I got this document? This document was checked in, and only me checked this document out by opening this document. 
[image]

Major and minor versioning is enabled.